# Server crashes because of SMP

Tags: linux-kernel, server-crashes, kernel-panic, smp

My web server is crashing every few days unless I disable SMP with "nosmp" parameter in Grub config. It is not an hardware failure because the problem persists after moving everything to a new machine. Does anyone know which application could make the SMP system freeze with no output in syslog ?

The only kernel related stuff I can see in syslog is this :

```
Mar  3 09:38:27 kronos kernel: [382373.472638] exiftool[19894]: segfault at 8 ip 00007fb481a87ef8 sp 00007fffe17b0c60 error 4 in libperl.so.5.18.2[7fb4819c5000+180000]
Mar  3 10:39:41 kronos kernel: [386050.013041] exiftool[1138]: segfault at 0 ip 00007ff9a7a716d5 sp 00007ffff0949030 error 6 in libperl.so.5.18.2[7ff9a7a45000+180000]
Mar  3 10:52:16 kronos kernel: [386805.647826] exiftool[8117]: segfault at 10 ip 00007f950a4acfa6 sp 00007fff247a7c20 error 4 in libperl.so.5.18.2[7f950a45e000+180000]
Mar  3 15:06:02 kronos kernel: [402044.307919] exiftool[1722]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f5eaaffe6d5 sp 00007ffff6e3dc10 error 6 in libperl.so.5.18.2[7f5eaafd2000+180000]
Mar  3 15:08:17 kronos kernel: [402179.401062] exiftool[3711]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f7dac3e86d5 sp 00007fff8eaec7d0 error 6 in libperl.so.5.18.2[7f7dac3bc000+180000]
```

Server config: 
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-031900rc3-generic x86_64)